# How to upgrade spring boot admin from 1.5 to 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

Is there any reference guide for spring boot admin upgrade?
I have a legacy app that I need to upgrade from 1.5 to 2.0, but the entire API has changed & there is 0 info in the official reference guide. https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/

For example, the main domain class now seems to be InstanceEvent, whereas it used to be 'Application'; but they hold completely different info.
Same with the class 'AbstractStatusChangeNotifier'; which now seems to use InstanceEvent & Spring webflux...

My more specific question is:
How can I get application info from spring boot admin 2.0?
I used to be able to do this; which now no longer exists in the api.

`public class XXXMailNotifier extends AbstractStatusChangeNotifier {`

```
@Override
protected void doNotify(ClientApplicationEvent event) {
    try {
        helper.setText(mailContentGenerator.statusChange(event), true);
    } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

String statusChange(ClientApplicationEvent event) throws IOException {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> content = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("name", event.getApplication().getName())
            .put("id", event.getApplication().getId())
            .put("healthUrl", event.getApplication().getHealthUrl())
            .put("managementUrl", event.getApplication().getManagementUrl())
            .put("serviceUrl", event.getApplication().getServiceUrl())
            .put("timestamp", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(new LocalDateTime(event.getApplication().getInfo().getTimestamp())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it might help anyone...
I looked in the code and found that I can get the info from the instance.registration object.
You can change the above in the below:

```
    @Override
protected Mono<Void> doNotify(InstanceEvent event, Instance instance) {
    try {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setSubject(format(subject, environment, pool, instance.getRegistration().getName(), event.getInstance().getValue()));
        helper.setText(mailContentGenerator.statusChange(event, instance, getLastStatus(event.getInstance())), true);

    public String statusChange(InstanceEvent event, Instance instance, String lastStatus) throws IOException {
    Registration registration = instance.getRegistration();
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> content = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("name", registration.getName())
            .put("id", instance.getId().getValue())
            .put("healthUrl", registration.getHealthUrl())
            .put("managementUrl", registration.getManagementUrl())
            .put("serviceUrl", registration.getServiceUrl())
            .put("timestamp", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.print(new LocalDateTime(instance.getStatusTimestamp())));
```